# seo toolkit - request is disallowed by a robots.txt rule

Tags: iis, seo

I am trying to run the SEO toolkit IIS extension on an application I have running but I keep getting the following error:

> The request is disallowed by a Robots.txt rule

Now I have edited the robots.txt file in both the application and the root website so they both have the following rules:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

But this makes no difference and the toolkit still won't run.

I have even tried deleting both robots.txt files and that still doesn't make any difference.

Does anyone know any other causes for the seo toolkit to be unable to run or how to solve this problem?

Comment: Which url triggers this violation ? do you have any robots.txt in a subfolder ?

Comment: The url of the application - the only robots.txt files I have (or removed) were in the root folder (main site) and application folder - sub site

Answer (score 0):

To allow all robots complete access I would recommend using the following syntax (according to [robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html))

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

> (or just create an empty "/robots.txt" file, or don't use one at all)

The [allow directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard#Allow_directive) is supported only by "some major crawlers". So perhaps the IIS Search Engine Optimization (SEO) Toolkit's crawler  doesn't.

Hope this helps. If it doesn't, you can also try going through  IIS SEO Toolkit's  [Managing Robots.txt and Sitemap Files learning resource](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/iis-search-engine-optimization-toolkit/managing-robotstxt-and-sitemap-files).

Comment: This makes no difference either - it is the same as the allow all rule that I applied above and as stated in the question I already tried removing the files

Answer (score 0):

1. Check to make sure the DNS record is pointing to the correct server
2. If you're searching for the file, account for case sensitivity - robots.txt vs Robots.txt
3. Verify that the Toolkit is actually attempting to visit the site. Check the IIS logs for the presence of the "iisbot" user-agent.

Comment: Also tried all of these with no success and the iis-bot show up in the logs

Answer (score 0):

The robot.txt may have been cached. Stop/restart/unload IIS (application). The robots.txt will refreshed. Open a browser reload the file. You can even delete the file to be sure that IIS is not caching it.

Comment: Hi, I have tried all of these but with no success - something is still causing the violation to occur

Answer (score 0):

Basically robots.text is a file that does not allow Google to crawl the pages which are disallowed by admin so Google ignores those pages that's why those pages never rank and google never shows that data.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.